# aws lambda crashes when connection is closed

Tags: database, go, redis, aws-lambda, database-connection

I am using golang in a lambda function to connect to redis. When I first call the lambda a new connection pool is created and further calls the lambda seems to use the pool to get connections. However when I added the con.close() line, the second call to the lambda crashes and the third call will recreate the pool. Is there any risk if I don't close the connection? Or can I close the connection some other way?

The error I get on cloud watch logs is "runtime error, invalid memory address or nil pointer" on the line  pool.Get() seems like the pool variable is nil?

```
func newPool(addr string) *redis.Pool {
  return &redis.Pool{
    MaxIdle: 3,
    IdleTimeout: 240 * time.Second,
    // Dial or DialContext must be set. When both are set, DialContext takes precedence over Dial.
    Dial: func () (redis.Conn, error) { return redis.Dial("tcp", addr) },
  }
}

var pool *redis.Pool

func init(){
   pool = newPool()
}



func Handle(ctx context.context, req events.APIGatewayWebsocketProxyRequest)(interface{},error){

  //make new redis connection

  con:= pool.get()

   con.close()

}
```

Comment: You can set the redis timeout in redis config,  it will automatically close the connection if client is idle for timeout period.

Comment: @CeriseLimón - I added the error in the question

Answer (score 0):

How about adding `defer con.close()` in Handle function? because after Handle function is called it will close the con.

Comment: @Yoell32- I tried that. It causes the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are closing the connection as soon as you open the connection, so yes the Lambda will kill itself.

You could keep the connection alive with a loop of some sort, process your messages then exit the loop to close the connection. Which would then in turn kill the Lambda again.

You could set your lambda to be [long-lived](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/long-lived.html) which would just keep incurring costs.

Once your Handle method is complete lambdas kill themselves.

Comment: @Joshua Lawson- I am doing other work between con:pool.get() and con.close()

Comment: con:= pool.get()

   con.close()

is not doing any work in between? Maybe your example is not complete?

the Close method closes the connections all together, as soon as that line is execute it will close the redis connection, looking at your example you close the connection straight after you open it.
https://godoc.org/github.com/go-redis/redis#Client.Close

Comment: @JoshuaLawson so I should not close the connection? What will happen if like 5 mins later the lambda is called again? Is the same connection used? Or if multiple lambdas are running at the same time?